# Genymotion and Virtualbox

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

When I try to open my virtual device from Genymotion it gives me

> Unable to start the virtual device.
>
> VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device.
>
> To find out the cause of the problem, start the virtual device from
>   VirtualBox.

And from VirtualBox :

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Samsung Galaxy S5 - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 1080x1920.
>
> VT-x is disabled in the BIOS. (VERR_VMX_MSR_VMXON_DISABLED).
>
> Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) Component: Console
>   Interface: IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}

Comment: Enable it in your BIOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable your Virtual Technology (VT-x) under CPU feature  in side BIOS.By default it is disabled so you have to enable it by using BIOS setting.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the `VT-x` is disabled in the BIOS.

Here you have a [tutorial](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html) to enable it. I also provide you a [video-tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFJYpT7L5ag) just in case you need more graphical explanation.